# purescript createClass fails to compile

Tags: purescript

a Node is a recursive data structure that has a name and an Array of children Nodes

Sample of my code:

```
newtype NodesState = NodesState {
    nodes  :: Array Node ,
    errors :: Array String 
}

nodes_state :: NodesState 
nodes_state = NodesState { nodes: [], errors: [] }

nodesList :: forall props. ReactClass props
nodesList = createClass $ spec nodes_state \ctx -> do 
    NodesState { nodes: nodes, errors: errors } <- readState ctx
```

I get the following error:

> The last statement in a 'do' block must be an expression, but this block ends with a binder.

I'm trying to do the same as showed in the purescript-by-example book:

```
addressBook = createClass $ spec initialState \ctx -> do 
    AppState { person: Person person@{ homeAddress: Address address }
             , errors 
             } <- readState ctx
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

`do a ← m` is like `m >>= \a →`. It is not a complete expression. If that is what the book says, it is wrong. I am not sure what your objective is, but what you are looking for may be:

```
nodesList :: forall props. ReactClass props
nodesList = createClass $ spec nodes_state readState
```